# Cannot get file data from the clipboard using Flex

Tags: apache-flex, file, drag-and-drop, air, clipboard

Given: A Flex TileList with the following event:

```
<mx:nativeDragDrop>
  <![CDATA[
    if(event.clipboard.hasFormat(ClipboardFormats.FILE_LIST_FORMAT)) {
      var files:Array = event.clipboard.getData(ClipboardFormats.FILE_LIST_FORMAT) as Array;

      for each(var file:File in files)
      {
        // file.data is null here!
      }

      this.listData.refresh();
    }
  ]]>
</mx:nativeDragDrop>
```

I am trying to create a list of thumbnails from jpegs that I drag into this TileList. Image.source can use the url to show the image, but I need to scale the image down first (hi rez photos) I already have the scaling part done except that I need BitmapData from the file and it has null for file.data.

ALSO, I have tried this:

```
var x:URLRequest = new URLRequest(value.file.url); // this is a local file (e.g. file:///C:/somefile.jpg)
var b:Bitmap = new Bitmap(x.data as BitmapData);
```

data is ALSO null! So frustrating. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume this is a part of an AIR application.  (Accessing the clipboard from a plain Flex app is not possible.)

I have no experience with AIR, but your second code block is clearly wrong.  An `URLRequest` instance does nothing in itself, it is but a static object storing the request details.  In order to fetch the data from that URL, you need to create a `Loader`, and pass the request to that loader like this:

```
var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest(value.file.url); // this is a local file (e.g. file:///C:/somefile.jpg)
var ldr:Loader = new Loader();
ldr.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function(event:Event):void {
   var b:Bitmap = event.target.content as Bitmap;
});
ldr.load(req);
```

Of course, you'd have to fill in the `Event.COMPLETE` handler. Note that the `Loader` class can be used to load SWF and image objects, for all everything else, you'd have to use `URLLoader` and parse the data yourself.

Regarding the `nativeDragDrop` block, here's a snippet from the [documentation](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/):

> Typically a handler for the
>   nativeDragEnter  or nativeDragOver 
>   event evaluates the data being
>   dragged, along with the drag actions
>   allowed, to determine whether an
>   interactive object can accept a drop.
>   To specify that an interactive object
>   is an eligible target, the event
>   handler must call the
>   NativeDragManager.acceptDrop() 
>   function, passing in a reference to
>   the object. If the user releases the
>   mouse button over the designated
>   object, the object becomes the drop
>   target and dispatches the
>   nativeDragDrop  event.

Are you calling `NativeDragManager.acceptDrop()` properly?

Comment: I'm not having issues with the drg/drp functionality. It's the fact that I cant get data from a file by accessing it. Thx for the URLRequest tip. Right after I posted this, I also tried:

   var x:File = new File(value.file.url); // x.data still null!

Could I use the Loader class in this case too?

Comment: ok it really comes down to this. Opening the file works. I can view information about the file. However, this is still breaking:

var x:File = new File(value.file.nativePath);
x.load();
var b:Bitmap = x.data as Bitmap; // x.data is still null!

Comment: Like I said, I'm not an AIR programmer, but by looking at the specs, I see that here again, you'll have to add an Event.COMPLETE listener, and read the data only in the listener.  Also, I'm don't think that you can cast data, a ByteArray attribute, into a Bitmap directly.

Comment: Looking at your original code again, it is very possible that in the nativeDragDrop handler, you also need to issue a load() call on the received file object before accessing its data attribute.